# How can a seeded Job be deleted automatically

Tags: jenkins, automation, cicd, jenkins-job-dsl, multibranch-pipeline

I have a multibranch pipeline created using DSL Plugin in Jenkins.
Les't call this pipeline `BuildPipeline`.
As a last step in the pipeline we are running this DSL script to seed one other Pipeline for Deploy the feature work to some environment.

```
...

  stage('Deploy Jobs Generation') {
    sh "set"
      step([
        $class              : 'ExecuteDslScripts',
        targets             : 'path/to/myScript.groovy',
        removedJobAction    : 'DELETE',
        removedViewAction   : 'DELETE'
      ])
  }

...
```

In myScript.groovy I have a line code like this:

```
pipelineJob("DeployPipeline") {
    ...
}
```

Everything is working fine. The problem comes when the branch is deleted, as the `BuildPipeline` gets deleted as expected but the seeded job `DeployPipeline` does not.

I need the seeded Job gets also deleted when the branch is deleted.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check out the [multibranch-action-triggers plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/multibranch-action-triggers/), you can use it to run a dedicated job that deletes the seed job when a branch is deleted.